how to do caching of initial prompts in langchain for a sql based chatbot
I am creating a chatbot application using Langchain/Ollama and Gemma2b. The application is working fine, but now I am stuck on speed optimizations.
With every request, I send the schema of the database, a few-shot examples retrieved from the database, and the user's questions. The common part is the database schema, which is sent with every request. I couldn't find any documentation on how to optimize this process. Attaching a screenshot for reference.
Querstion: Is there any way where I can avoid sending schema every single time?

